# Option clashing Latex error while using "switch" option for lineno package

Tags: lineno, option-clash

I am working in two column paper. The line numbers for both columns are coming left side. It is fine for the left column whereas the line numbers for the right column is merging with the text. To avoid this I used "switch" option to print the right column line numbers at the right. But I encountered option clash error while using it. Please check and advise.

The package called:

```
\usepackage[switch,mathlines]{lineno}
```

And the error I faced:

```
! LaTeX Error: Option clash for package lineno.

See the LaTeX manual or LaTeX Companion for explanation.
Type  H <return>  for immediate help.
 ...                                              
                                                  
l.24 
     
?
```

Comment: Please show your `MWE` always in executable format, i.e., from `\documentclass` to `\end{document}`

Comment: Does your code attempt to load the `lineno` package more than once?

Comment: if (as the message you quote says) you type `h` to that prompt you get a suggested fix specific to this clash.  But you are loading the package twice, and only showing us one of the calls so we can not really help.